# Does anyone know any good online resources for gaming on Linux Machines?

Tags: linux

Ubuntu to be precise.

And I am looking for lists of games with a short review or some newsgroup or something where I can find out about the latest releases.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What kind of resource do you want?  Are you looking for games?  Information on games?  It's impossible to tell.

Comment: @StrixVaria, you are quite right, post updated.

Comment: See [Reddit's /r/linux_gaming/ subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Useful resources are:

- [Linux Games](http://www.linuxgames.com)
- [The Linux Game Tome](http://www.happypenguin.org/) (unfortunately is down at the moment due to a "big" data failure)
- [Gaming On Linux](http://www.gamingonlinux.info)

In addition, the following "not too old" links list about 10-15 RPG games. They are not really reviews but contains a mini description with the list of features

- [42 Best Free Linux Games](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20080510052539217/Games.html)
- [42 More of the Best Free Linux Games](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20080522164112313/Games-Part2.html)
- [42 Best Linux Commercial Games](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20080530054213402/CommercialGames.html)

Then in Ubuntu [gaming forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=93), you can found another big list of [useful gaming resource](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=359842).

Comment: i’d like to add http://penguspy.com and http://lgdb.org